# 2D Green's function and 3D divergence

Tags: electrostatics, greens-functions

I need to find the following exrpression for the green's function in 2D:

$G(\rho)=\frac 1 {2 \pi} ln(c \rho)$ where c is some constant.

So I initially used the laplace equation in order to find an expression for it, for G:

$G= Aln\rho + B$, whee A,B are some constants, which we can evaluate if we have some initial boundary conditions.

Now I use the divergence theorem in 3D :

$\int_V \nabla(\nabla G)dV=\int_{(V)}\nabla G d\vec A $

Now the problem I have is that my Green's function, since it's a 2D function, is not dependent from the z component. That's why I thought of using a cylindrical volume and dividing the left integral in the one that contains x and y, both expressed in polar coordinates which is multiplied with an integral that has the z component, if we assume that the z goes from (-h) to (h). But I don't know what to do with the right integral, since my green function has no z component. Any help as to how I should proceed would really help me

Comment: In 3d, the integrals are over a region (volume) or over the boundary of that region. What is a region or 'volume' in 2d? What is it's boundary?

Comment: We can consider a cylinder with a finite volume

Comment: If you're working in 2d then it isn't useful to think of cylinders with finite volume. A 'volume' element in 2d is an *area* and it's boundary is a *curve*, so can you see what the divergence theorem should read in 2d?

Comment: @Sal I was able to solve it. But I wanted to ask something else too, do you mind if we use a chat room ?

Comment: Sure, which room?

Comment: Idk, we have to create one, but I don't know how to. Maybe if we keep chatting here the option will pop up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131626/discussion-between-imbaf-and-sal).